# SQLITE Database Tables in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to create several tables in one database, in my android app.

Each table is named differently, and the I don't find out the name until after the program starts running, so it's all dynamic.

However, the first table gets created, and any new ones, don't
I get "no such table" error.

This is what I do to create the table:

```
private class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String TAG = "SQLiteHelper";
    private String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + helper.getTableName() + "(" + helper.getTableColumns() + ");";


    public SQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, helper.getDatabaseName(), null, helper
                .getDatabaseVersion());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        Log.d(TAG, "database created");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + helper.getTableName());
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

helper is an object that is passed to the DB constructor

```
public ProductDB(Context context, IDatabaseHelper helper) {
    this.context = context;
    this.helper = helper;
}
```

The first time the db is created, everything works and everything as fine,
but as soon as I need to add a second table, when I try accessing it, it crashes

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: lines of code that create table for the second time plz..

Comment: SQLiteHelper dbHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context);
because the IDatabaseHelper Object is different, it should create a table with a different name, however, i've come to realize that simply the "oncreate" method of the sqlitehelper doesnt get called

Comment: That's it. I was also doubted on onCreate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SQLiteDatabase db;
 SQLiteHelper dbHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context);
 db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + helper.getTableName() + "(" + helper.getTableColumns() + ")");
```